# Airflow webserver -p 8080 results in attributeerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I'm using a macOS development box and have installed airflow, unfortunately running `airflow webserver -p 8080` results in an "AttributeError"

```
value = getattr(current_model, attribute) AttributeError: type object 'TaskInstance' has no attribute 'log'
```

`pip freeze` says my version is `airflow==1.7.1.2`

My python is `Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 11:24:55)`

Here is the sequence of events:

- I made an anaconda environment
- I installed some packages, including
  airflow
- `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/airbnb/airflow.git`
- set the `AIRFLOW_HOME` variable in my `.bash_profile`
- `airflow initdb` worked fine
- `airflow webserver -p 8080` gives the following

  ```
  [2016-06-13 14:07:09,768] {models.py:161} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/trogdor/airflow/dags
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/bin/airflow", line 15, in <module>
      args.func(args)
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 418, in webserver
      app = cached_app(conf)
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 135, in cached_app
      app = create_app(config)
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 75, in create_app
      Session, name="Task Instances", category="Browse"))
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 318, in __init__
      menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 771, in __init__
      self._refresh_cache()
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 847, in _refresh_cache
      self._list_columns = self.get_list_columns()
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 980, in get_list_columns
      excluded_columns=self.column_exclude_list,
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 517, in get_column_names
      column, path = tools.get_field_with_path(self.model, c)
    File "/Users/trogdor/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/tools.py", line 144, in get_field_with_path
      value = getattr(current_model, attribute)
  AttributeError: type object 'TaskInstance' has no attribute 'log'
  ```

Comment: yes. there are bunch of similar errors popping up due to bad commit somehow. See the archive here with relevant error http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-commits/201606.mbox/thread?2

Comment: oh, thanks, good to see it get fixed